# Laravel - How to NOT use a layout

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel, laravel-3

I'm using laravel with controllers layout. But there are some parts of my app where I don't want to use a layout (for example, when returning data to the payment gateway request, for wich I send XML data). I just want to pass data to my view and render it alone, with no need for a layout.

How can I do that? I've been trying some approaches but none worked for this. I can successfuly change what layout to render, but I can't set to render the view without a layout.

Thanks!

**Edit: Let me explain it better**

My default layout is set in Base_Controller. Then all my controllers extends it but in one of them I need no layout, as I told above. Maybe I need to unset the default layout or something like that, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return something from your controller action to bypass the layout.

```
function get_xml($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    return View::make('user.xml', $user);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a views/user/xml.php (or blade.php)?  At least you know it definitely bypassed something!  :D

Comment: Yes, I have. But your question lighted a spark in my mind and I found what was wrong. I was testing with a view file that had @section() and @endsection. After removing them, it finally worked :D Thank you man!

Comment: If you have the layout set in the controller `protected $layout = "page.layout";` following this method will return the view the layout. This DOES NOT by-pass the layout.

Comment: @Shane I suspect you are using Laravel 4 or 5, this question & answer were about Laravel 3.

Answer (score 2):

On your controller functions, you can simply return a string, which will be thrown back to the browser as-is. Alternatively, you can craft a `Laravel\Response` object, which will allow you to fine-tune your site's output a lot more than just returning a string.

The `Response` class has a few tricks up its sleeve that are not mentioned on the docs: [default return](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Response.html#_make), [JSON](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Response.html#_json), [forced download](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Response.html#_download).

You're more interested in the first one, which will allow you to correctly set the content-type of the response to `application/xml`. In addition to this, you can *still* use views for XML! Generate the view as you would with `View::make`, but instead of directly returning it, store it in a variable. To render it, call `render()` on it - it will return the output.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way....

suppose there is a `main` layout

```
 <body>

        @yield('content')

</body>
```

This `content` will be where the view will be inserted.

Now,

if you want to use layout, Make the view page like this:

```
@layout('main')

@section('content')
 blah blah your content
@endsection
```

**If you don't want to use layout, omit the codes above.**

In **controller**, the code will be same for both the files.

```
 return View::make('index');
```

Comment: OP is using controller layouts, not blade layouts; so this doesn't apply.

Comment: @PhillSparks that's the convenent way. otherwise, just need to add `$this->layout=''` and layout gone....

Comment: Yes, although you'll still need to return a response at that point anyway.

Comment: Nope, when you use controller layouts you don't have to return anything, because the controller will use the layout automatically (even if you don't add anything to the layout)

Comment: @PhillSparks That is a misconception. You **have** to return response. Difference is, In blade layout, you have to **explicitely** return it while in controller layout, laravel does it for you.

Comment: that's what I said by "the controller will use the layout automatically" - if you say to some people "you must **return** a response" then they will thing they must use a **return** in their actions.